# Best practice for handling multiple exceptions in multiple methods same way in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have a class `ServerApi` with methods `callApiA`, `callApiB`, ...
Each of this methods returns subclass of the `ServerApiResponse`.
Communication to server is managed by `HttpClient`.

There are many things that could go wrong, for example:

- server has crashed
- no Internet connection
- timeout

Also server could send meta-response, for example:

- session expired
- server overloaded

Now I need to handle all of this situations in one place. Is it okey to catch `Exception` in all `callApiX` methods, and handle it in one place by checking exception type by `instance of` method or is there any better solution?

```
... callApiA(...){
    try{
        ...
    } catch(Exception e){
        return handleApiCallException(e);
    }
}

... callApiB(...){
    try{
        ...
    } catch(Exception e){
        return handleApiCallException(e);
    }
}

...

... callApiX(...){
    try{
        ...
    } catch(Exception e){
        return handleApiCallException(e);
    }
}

... handleAPiCallException(Exception e){
    if(e instance of IOException){
        ...
    } else if(e instanceof ...){
        ...
    } ...
}
```

Comment: Can you really handle all situations in one place. Maybe your service should only report the problem (either by rethrowing the exception or wrapping it in a corresponding exception of the service layer).

Comment: @isnot2bad there could be many exception from i.e. `HttpClient`.

Comment: @Ari why not use `Exception` class?

Comment: @Ari Yes, but maybe just some of them can be handled by the service itself. Others (e.g. connection timeout) should bubble up to the user interface layer so that the user can be notified. Note that HttpClient tries to recovery automatically by retrying requests up to 5 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't always want to `return` something when you *catch* an *exception*. I would do something like that:

```
catch (IOException | AnotherException | ... e) {
    //Handle exceptions here..
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. The problem is that there are many exceptions and I need to catch them and handle the same way for many methods.

Comment: @Ari Then you might want to consider making these methods `throw` the exception and handle them within one helper method in the caller.

Comment: @MarounMaroun you should mention here it is applicable only to later versions. :)